# HM-10 controller is not responding to AT commands

Tags: arduino-nano, ble

I recently purchased new HM-10 module, because old one was clone and it lacks AT+TYPE command. I connected it to my Arduino and I don't know why but I cant see any response in SerialMonitor.

I even tried to use this `ble_help()` function which worked on my old HM-10 controller but here nothing is returned.

Pins:

- TXD --- D2
- RXD --- D3

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); //Create software serial instance, pins of your choice

char c = ' ';


// Initialization
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Sketch:   ");   Serial.println(__FILE__);
  Serial.print("Uploaded: ");   Serial.println(__DATE__);
  Serial.println(" ");

  BTserial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("BTserial started at 9600");
  ble_help();
}

String str_ii = "";
int ii_0 = 0;
void ble_help(){
  BTserial.println("AT+HELP"); // list all AT+ commands
  while (true){ // loop to print all AT+ commands
    char in_char = BTserial.read();
    if (int(in_char)==-1 or int(in_char)==42){continue;}
    str_ii+=in_char;
    if (in_char=='\n'){
      if (str_ii==String('\r')+String('\n')){
        if (ii_0 == 0){
          ii_0 = 1;
          continue;
        }
        break; // break after more than 1 empty carriage return and newline
      }
      Serial.print(str_ii);
      str_ii = "";
    }
  }
}

// Arduino Execution Loop
void loop()
{
  // Read from the Bluetooth module and send to the Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (BTserial.available())
  {
    String hm10msg = "";
    char c;

    while((c = BTserial.read()) != -1) {
      hm10msg += c;
      delay(10);
    }

    Serial.println("Received: " + hm10msg);
  }

  // Read from the Serial Monitor and send to the Bluetooth module
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    c = Serial.read();
    BTserial.write(c);
    //Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried different baudrates for the HM-10? It might be configured for a different baudrate than 9600

Comment: I will try. But 9600 should be default as far as i know

Comment: Tried every possibility but it doesnt work

Comment: With a new module like this, I just skip the code and connect it straight to my PC with a UART-USB adapter. That way, I can send commands directly from the Serial Monitor and also try out different baud rates easily. Do you have an adapter like this? If you don't, it's possible to use the one on your Nano.

Comment: Ok its working now. I have to use BTserial.print(c) instead of BTserial.write(c).